# Get popular Arch packages

Tags: bash

Get a list of popular Arch Linux packages with a popularity greater or equal than the given one.

It asks for the popularity if it isn't given. Then gets the total number of packages and iterates until it gets the whole list of packages - one thousand at a time, because if I try to grab them all the API gives an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function get_popularity() {
    local popularity
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        popularity=$1
    else
        read -rp "Popularity [0-100]: " popularity
    fi
    while [[ $popularity -lt 0 || $popularity -gt 100 ]] ; do
        read -rp "Popularity [0-100]: " popularity
    done
    echo $popularity
}

function get_total_pkgs() {
    local total
    total=$(curl -sX "GET" -H "accept: application/json" \
        "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages?limit=1&offset=0" \
        | jq ".total")
    echo $total
}

function get_popular_packages() {
    local x total popularity packages limit
    total=$1
    popularity=$2
    packages=()
    x=0
    limit=1000
    while [ $x -le $total ]; do
        packages+=$(curl -sX "GET" -H "accept: application/json" \
            "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages?limit=$limit&offset=$x" \
            | jq ".packagePopularities[]" \
            | jq "select( .popularity >= $popularity )" \
            | jq ".name")
        x=$(($x+$limit))
    done
    echo "${packages[@]}"
}

function main () {
    popularity=$(get_popularity "$@")
    packages=$(get_popular_packages $(get_total_pkgs) $popularity)
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: If you are asking for help writing against an API, link the API docs: https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably address these Shellcheck issues:

```
265799.sh:32:9: warning: Use array+=("item") to append items to an array. [SC2179]
265799.sh:37:14: note: $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables. [SC2004]
265799.sh:37:17: note: $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables. [SC2004]
265799.sh:44:5: warning: Variable was used as an array but is now assigned a string. [SC2178]
265799.sh:44:37: warning: Quote this to prevent word splitting. [SC2046]
265799.sh:44:55: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
```

---

The implementation doesn't match the description.  "Popularity greater or equal than the given one" implies that we are to give a package name as argument, but the program wants a number.  I'm guessing that's a mistake in the description, but it emphasises the need to be clear and unambiguous in program documentation (an aspect often overlooked).

---

I don't like the command asking for input if the argument is missing - I'd prefer a clear error message showing how to use the command correctly.  That makes it easier to debug its use in scripts, for example.

---

It's not necessary to use three invocations of `jq` in the pipe:

> ```
>         | jq ".packagePopularities[]" \
>         | jq "select( .popularity >= $popularity )" \
>         | jq ".name"
> ```

It's more efficient to use its internal pipelining:

```
        | jq ".packagePopularities[] | select(.popularity >= $popularity) | .name"
```

That saves the program having to serialise and deserialise the data twice in the middle.

---

There's no need to store results like this:

> ```
> packages=()
> while [ $x -le $total ]; do
>     packages+=$(command …)
> done
> echo "${packages[@]}"
> ```

We can simply print as we go:

```
while [ $x -le $total ]; do
    command …
done
```

That means we don't need any Bash functionality, and can write a portable (POSIX) shell script instead.  That's likely to be leaner in operation (e.g. if system shell is Dash, which is much lower overhead than Bash).

---

The `main` function captures the output of `get_popular_packages` into a variable, but then finishes it without using it for anything.  I expected something more like

```
popularity=$(get_popularity "$@")
get_popular_packages $(get_total_pkgs) $popularity
```

Comment: I don't know why it breaks when I use the internal pipelining of qd.

I'm going to echo the list of packages so I can source this script from another one and install the packages in the other script.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with that - I just believed what I read on the man page.  I've barely used jq myself.

Answer (score 2):

First, as someone who writes a lot of bash, I would recommend rewriting this in something other than bash. You're using bash as a programming language (and trying quite hard to make it readable), but it's simply not the best programming language.

- The basic idea of gluing together a bunch of curl and jq commands seems solid.
- I would contact the maintainer of the API, and politely ask them to document the API limit or remove it.
- You're repeatedly using `\` at the end of a line, followed by `|` on the next line. Instead just put `|` at the end of the first line.
- Separate out the logic of getting all the API responses (`get_all_package_json`) and restricting to the popular ones (`get_popular_packages`). jq can take one JSON object per line.
- I would recommend outputting the packages via `sort -u` to avoid errors and for user convenience.

Comment: ``\``⤶`|` is arguably a style choice - I happen to like it, because it makes pipeline continuation lines quite obvious when scanning the line starts (we don't want to keep indenting for each line here - I've been known to have 10-20 lines in one pipe).  When I do that, I don't indent the pipeline continuations the same as the argument continuations, though.

Comment: It's definitely a style choice. I don't like trailing \, because you if you accidentally add a space after it, everything silently breaks but looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the suggestions. Nobody suggested to stop downloading when the packages have lesser popularity than the given one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function usage() {
    cat <<EOF
Usage: get_popular_packages.sh popularity
EOF
    exit 1
}

function get_popularity() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        echo $1
    else
        usage
    fi
}

function get_total_packages() {
    curl -sX "GET" -H "accept: application/json" \
        "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages?limit=1&offset=0" \
        | jq ".total"
}

function get_packages() {
    curl -sX "GET" -H "accept: application/json" \
        "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/api/packages?limit=$2&offset=$3" \
         | jq ".packagePopularities[]" \
         | jq "select( .popularity >= $1 )" \
         | jq ".name"
}

function get_popular_packages() {
    local x total limit
    popularity=$(get_popularity "$@")
    total=$(get_total_packages)
    x=0
    limit=2000
    while [ $x -le $total ]; do
        get_packages $popularity $limit $x
        x=$(($x+$limit))
    done
}

get_popular_packages "$@"
```

Comment: You probably want to `usage >&2` in the error case, so the message appears on the error stream.

Comment: Are the packages returned in order of popularity? It's not clear to me that they are.

Comment: I just tried it, and I can confirm that the packages are sorted by popularity. I hadn't really checked it before, that's why I didn't mention it when I opened the question.